# Connection to sql server 2014 with php

Tags: php

I am trying to connect database in sql server 2014 with php as follows:

First I have this script in conexaosql.php:

```
class Conexao
{
    private static $connection;

    private function __construct(){}

    public static function getConnection() {

        $pdoConfig  = DB_DRIVER . ":". "Server=" . DB_HOST . ";";
        $pdoConfig .= "Database=".DB_NAME.";";

        try {
            if(!isset($connection)){
                $connection =  new PDO($pdoConfig, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
                $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            return $connection;
         } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $mensagem = "Drivers disponiveis: " . implode(",", PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
            $mensagem .= "\nErro: " . $e->getMessage();
            throw new Exception($mensagem);
         }
     }
}
```

Then I call this script and I have the following code:

```
define('DB_HOST'        , "xxxx");
define('DB_USER'        , "xxxx");
define('DB_PASSWORD'    , "xxxx");
define('DB_NAME'        , "xxxx");
define('DB_DRIVER'      , "sqlsrv");

require ("conexaosql.php");

try{

    $Conexao    = Conexao::getConnection();
    $query      = $Conexao->query("SELECT Pago FROM UTE02.dbo.Recibos");
    $produtos   = $query->fetchAll();

 }catch(Exception $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;

 }
```

I get the following error when I run the code:

> mysql,sqlite Erro: could not find driver

I'm using php 8.1 and apache. I leave the [link](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFSTZattHo/Yg8zuJvrzPtZ3jhvH9-Xlw/view?utm_content=DAFSTZattHo&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link&utm_source=publishsharelink)  with images from phpinfo()

Comment: Are you on Linux...? But "SQL Server" is a Microsoft database system, right?

Comment: @Juan Yes, I'm on linux and the SQL server is on windows server 2012 R2

Comment: So you need to install something like a "Microsoft ODBC Driver", right...? Have you done this kind of installation...?

Comment: @Juan No, but do I need to do it on windows or linux?

Comment: Your PHP pages are on a Linux Server...? So you must install ODBC on Linux Server. May be this link can help you : [ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Juan I ran the commands for ubuntu, because my server is ubuntu server 20.04, but the error remains.

Comment: You have the link of @Josh which can help you. Maybe it's not the same command or installation principle.

Comment: @Juan I show the phpinfo() differences in the question for how it is now in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxT3w.jpg), but the error remains

Comment: This is no longer a purely PHP problem (subject on which I can sometimes help) but a problem installing ODBC on a Linux server.
Maybe you need to create a new question...? Did you search on StackOverFlow if there were any Posts about this...?

Comment: @Juan But what should I put in a new question to solve the problem? I don't know how to construct the question

Comment: What I'm suggesting to you is just an idea. But you can create a new question on "Installing ODBC driver for Microsoft SQL Server on Linux". And you put in this question the command that you launched and the error that you encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by running the following commands:

```
# Microsoft ODBC 17
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

#Download appropriate package for the OS version - Ubuntu 18.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17

# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev

# Microsoft ODBC 17
# 8.1
sudo apt-get -y install php-pear php8.1-dev
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar8.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar8.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize8.1
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config8.1

sudo pecl uninstall -r sqlsrv 
sudo pecl uninstall -r pdo_sqlsrv 
sudo pecl -d php_suffix=8.1 install sqlsrv
sudo pecl -d php_suffix=8.1 install pdo_sqlsrv
sudo su
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
exit
sudo phpenmod -v 8.1 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [PDO_SQLSRV](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) driver to access the database. You have only installed support for MySQL and SQLite.

If you run a Linux server, you have to install and use [ODBC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).

Comment: Does this installation have to be done on the Linux side? Is there any command in linux to install this dll?

Comment: Your link refers to a page that talks about DLL files... But @Anónimo is under Linux

Comment: @Anónimo On your PHP server.

Comment: Install a DLL on Linux Server...????

Comment: @Juan Indeed: But the DLL gives a link to for a extension which runs with Linux: The PDO_SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows. For Linux, see ODBC and » Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux.

So the Driver must be adjusted and the correct libary for Linux you can find here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

Comment: @Josh Can you tell me which commands to do this installation?

Comment: Yes for ODBC. It's why I talk about it in the comments :)

Comment: Anonimo: You can find the installation instructions on the linked pages. @juan Sorry, I haven't seen your comments :/

Comment: @Josh I already executed what you suggested and I still executed what is in this [link](https://www.imaginelinux.com/install-odbc-on-ubuntu/), , but I still have the error

Comment: @Josh I show the phpinfo() differences in the question for how it is now in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxT3w.jpg), but the error remains